# How to get Gravity forms to generate dynamic confirmation message?

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using gravity forms on a business directory. I want to edit the confirmation message such when a user contact the business owner on the directory such that the message shows the contact details of that particular business owner dynamically.

Is this possible and how can it be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check out this link as the source code for your solution.
http://pastebin.com/XGdXVXfn

In your html box, you will need to add the follow sample code as to display the fields that has been filled before.

```
<strong>Name: {entry_id:1} </strong><br/>
<strong>Email: {entry_id:2} </strong><br/>
<strong>Delivery location: {entry_id:5} </strong><br/>
```